# Why is there a curled bracket on the List?

Tags: java

Recently stumped upon this line in a program, and I have no idea what the bracket for (`List<Level>`) is for . Anybody got any idea ?

`List<Level> levelList = (List<Level>)dao.getAllLevels();`

Comment: Those are not curled brackets `{}`. Those are round brackets `()` (also called open brackets or parentheses). See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket

Comment: Here's a tip next time you see a piece of code you don't understand, just remove it and see what the compiler says. If you don't understand the error message from the compiler, just type it into Google and read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called [typecasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion). The data returned from dao.getAllLevels() is being casted into type `List`.

This operation might not always be successful, and in that case `jvm/jre` throws a `ClassCastException`. You can read more about object typecasting in Java [here](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting).

More about java and type-casting on Stackoverflow:

1. [Java Type-casting Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453114/java-typecasting-question)

Answer (score 0):

This casts the result of `dao.getAllLevels();` to a `List`

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on what `getAllLevels` method is returning.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a cast. It's used to enforce the type of the following variable, in this case, to be sure that dao.getAllLevels() returns an object of type List.